# libprotobuf ERROR when accessing the output tensor in Tensorflow C++ API

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensor

I'm using tensorflow C++ API for inference. I was able to build a standalone tensorflow library, loading the optimized graph, and feeding an image.

I'm able to print the tensor using the following code:

```
    // run the image through the model.
    std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
    Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, resized_tensor}}, {output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
    if (!run_status.ok()) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
        return -1;
    }

      std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << "\n";
```

and then I get the following output:

```
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,480,720,3] values: [[[58.4225044 79.0690613 94.4875641]]]...>
```

but after adding this line:

```
cv::Mat rotMatrix(outputs[0].dim_size(1), outputs[0].dim_size(2), CV_32FC1, outputs[0].flat<float>().data());
```

or this line:

```
float *p = outputs[0].flat<float>().data();
```

I get the following error:

```
2019-06-26 14:19:29.040705: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:118] File already exists in database: google/protobuf/any.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried it using bazel, qmake, and cmake and built protocol buffer again from source but without any help..

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution? Thx

Comment: I can’t really recall right now, but I guess it was a problem with versions incompatibility. Try to build and execute everything inside nvidia-docker to avoid running into problems with the system environment. Once I’m back from vacation and you still face this problem, I’ll try to post a solution for this question.